# If X can be topologically embedded in a metric space Y how would one define the metric on X?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I have an idea of how one might go about doing it, but it's never explicitly mentioned in the books or anywhere on the net for that manner (at least not where I looked which includes this site), so I just wanted to make sure. So suppose we have a homeomorphism $f$ of $X$ into $Y$ which is equipped with a metric $d$; how would one define the metric on $X$? And show that this metric induces the same original topology on $X$.

Comment: Set the distance between $a$ and $b$ in $X$ as the distance between $a$ and $b$ in $Y$.

Comment: Yes that's what I was thinking but to me that wasn't entirely satisfactory. Homeomorphisms technically don't care about distances and as such 2 points that were originally "close" could end up very far in Y and vice versa; so to me the metric on the image Y was not a good reflection of how points were originally distributed on X.

Comment: So is there some other way to define a metric on $X$?

Comment: @Leonid: That’s irrelevant: even if $X$ already had some metric compatible with its topology, this just says that it has another metric, induced by the embedding, that is topologically equivalent to the original one. Embedding preserves **topological** properties, not **metric** properties.

Comment: @Leonid: If all that you know about $X$ is that $f:X\to Y$ is an embedding, and $d$ is a metric on $Y$ that generates the topology on $Y$, then the only metric on $X$ to which you have immediate access is given by $\delta(x,y)=d(f(x),f(y))$. Of course you can use any other metric that you can prove is topologically equivalent to $\delta$.

Comment: Ah yes, it's very clear now. Thank you.

Comment: @Leonid: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ be a topological space and $i: X\to Y$ a topological embedding into a metric space $(Y, d)$.

The most important thing to note is that $S$ is open in $X$ if and only if $f(S)$ is open in $Y$. Equivalently, $S$ is a neighborhood around $x\in X$ if and only if $f(S)$ is a neighborhood around $f(x)\in Y$.
Therefore, intuitively speaking, having an embedding means that we can effectively treat $X$ as a subspace of $Y$.

So to define a metric $\delta$ on $X$, we can transport our points to $Y$ and measure the distance there: $$
  \delta(x, x') := d(f(x), f(x')).
$$ Proving that this indeed is a metric is essentially just transporting the metric axioms on $Y$ through the injection $f$.

To show that the topology induced by $(X, \delta)$ is the same as the original one, we can just verify that the notion of „neighborhood“ is the same (as it is purely definable by the notion of open sets, hence only depends on the topology): note that the following are equivalent for $x\in X, S\subseteq X$:

1. $S$ is a neighborhood around $x$
2. $f(S)$ is a neighborhood around $f(x)$
3. $f(S)$ contains an $\epsilon$-ball around $f(x)$ with regards to $d$
4. $S$ contains an $\epsilon$-ball around $x$ with regards to $\delta$

**Edit:** Your title said „topological embedding“, and your post just spoke of „homeomorphic“. Therefore I chose to show the more general principle.